# Yahoo Finance Webservice API is down?

Tags: matlab, yahoo, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I've been using the Yahoo Finance Webservice for a few months now to fetch stock data in JSON format using the following URL: http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/AAPL/quote?format=json&view=detail

**It has been working perfectly.**However, as of today this is simply hitting a 404 error and I can't seem to find a possible work around. I understand Yahoo has made some changes to Yahoo finance and their other APIs. Does anyone have a potential solution?

Thanks.

Comment: @excaza This isn't a duplicate question. I am not facing any issues related to using a User Agent or "bypass==true" parameter. As I said I have been using the webservice for the last few months for a university project. Today is the first time I am facing difficulties with it.

Comment: Stock price data error: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<!-- status code : 404 -->
<!-- Error: GET -->
<!-- host machine: media-router19.prod.media.ir2.yahoo.com -->
<!-- timestamp: 1493397931.000 -->
<!-- url: http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/MSFT/quote?format=json&view=detail-->
<H1>Error</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Could not process this "GET" request.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>

Comment: An undocumented API working perfectly does not magically make it a valid API to use, nor is Yahoo obligated to continue supporting it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It happen to me too since yesterday, fix it by using YQL API.